# Calculating elapsed time using delta

Tags: java, math, timedelta

I must be making some silly mistake in my code, In my head this should work but the timer works a bit too fast ( I want to get time left in seconds).

My code:

```
timeElapsed = 0;
timeLeft = 60;
//delta = time it took to get through one frame (60 fps). 

timeElapsed += delta/getFramesPerSecond(); //FPS = 60f
timeLeft -= timeElapsed; //timeLeft starts at 60 (seconds)
timeDisplay = "Time left: " + timeLeft;
```

I have checked that FPS is always 60, what am I missing here?

Delta sample prints:

```
0.016969847
0.017038532
0.017123796
0.017026689
0.016969848
0.017059453
0.01697774
0.016987609
0.017073665
0.017035767
0.01708432
```

Comment: Possible Integer division giving `0` which would make timeLeft always have 60

Comment: Sorry I should have specified all variables are float

Comment: Inconclusive with the sample shown. What is the original value of `timeElapse`, `timeLeft`, and  `delta`? Is `timeDisplay` being print out or it it supposed to be changing a label on a UI? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I added the information :) The time is being printed as intended

Comment: From the information gathered, delta seems to be calculating zero.

Comment: @gtgaxiola If it was 0 then the timer would not move at all I think. I added some sample prints of delta.

Comment: @WEDEBE for better answers, you should try to create and post a complete example that reproduces the problem, including variable declarations etc.

Comment: @assylias All the info I have is there. What else do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeElapsed+timeLeft` should be a constant (thus both should change by the same amount in opposite directions), however, you are repeatedly reducing `timeLeft` by `timeElapsed`

In a demonstrative example with steps 1 in `timeElapsed`, your code gives

```
timeElapsed   timeLeft
    0            60
    1            59
    2            57
    3            54
    4            50
    5            45
    6            39
    7            32
```

Change the code to

```
timeDelta    = delta/getFramesPerSecond(); 
timeElapsed += timeDelta; 
timeLeft    -= timeDelta; 
timeDisplay  = "Time left: " + timeLeft;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain your answer :) I had to change `delta/getFramesPerSecond();` to just `delta` since I'm already calculating the delta and this is called every frame.